# Get-Process avoid stderr redirection with Start-Transcript

Tags: powershell

My code looks like this:

```
Start-Transcript -Path "C:/test.txt"
Write-Host (Get-Date).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss") "Starting"
$processes_using_oci_dll    =   Get-Process |  ? { (get-process -id $_.id -module | ? {$_.filename -like "*\oci.dll"})} 2> $null
Write-Host (Get-Date).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss") "Ending"
```

When watching its output through a powershell cli, it looks nice, the `Get-Process ... 2> $null` avoids the permission issues from being displayed on screen.

Nevertheless, when I open the file C:/test.txt, I can see a huge amount of entries such as

```
+ ... dll    =    Get-Process |  ? { (get-process -id $_.id -module | ? {$_ ...
+                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (System.Diagnost... (aesm_service):Process) [Get-Process], 
ProcessCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldnotEnumerateModules,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetProcessCommand
get-process : No se pueden enumerar los módulos del proceso "REDACTED".
```

My question is: How can I effectively keep these warnings from being Transcripted to the file C:/test.txt?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @zett42 it works like a charm! What about posting your comment as an answer, so I can accept it and upvote it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from redirecting the error stream (#2) to `$null`, you can also use the `-ErrorAction` (alias `-EA`) [common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters?view=powershell-7.2#-erroraction), which is more readable and more efficient, as the error is suppressed at the source. It also gives you additional options, as follows:

- `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` suppresses the error message and continues executing the command.
- `-ErrorAction Ignore` suppresses the error message and continues executing the command. Unlike `SilentlyContinue`, `Ignore` doesn't add the error message to the `$Error` automatic variable.

```sh
$processes_using_oci_dll = Get-Process -EA Ignore | ? { (get-process -id $_.id -module -EA Ignore | ? {$_.filename -like "*\oci.dll"})}
```